# Incomplete Type error in Builder pattern implementation

Tags: c++, builder

I'm playing around the Builder pattern. And, I come across the 'incomplete return type' issue. What should be the correct way to implement it?

```
// HtmlElement.h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class HtmlBuilder;
class HtmlElement
{
  string name, text;
  HtmlElement()
    {
      cout << "HtmlElement created\n";
    }
 public:
  ~HtmlElement()
    {
      cout << "HtmlElement destroyed\n";
    }

  static HtmlBuilder create();

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const HtmlElement& obj)
  {
    return os
      << "name: " << obj.name
      << " text: " << obj.text << endl;
  }

  friend class HtmlBuilder;

};

// HtmlBuilder.h

#include "HtmlElement.h"

using namespace std;
class HtmlBuilder
{
  HtmlElement root;
 public:
  HtmlBuilder()
    {
      root.name = "root";
      root.text = "dummy";
    }
  ~HtmlBuilder()
    {

    }
  HtmlElement build() { return root; }
};

// HtmlElement.cpp

    HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::create()
    {
      return HtmlBuilder();
    }
```

the compiler is throwing error related to incomplete type.

```
HtmlElement.cpp:4:33: error: return type 'class HtmlBuilder' is incomplete
4 | HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::create()
  |                                 ^
HtmlElement.cpp: In static member function 'static void HtmlElement::create()':
HtmlElement.cpp:6:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class HtmlBuilder'
6 |   return HtmlBuilder();
  |                      ^
In file included from HtmlElement.cpp:1:
HtmlElement.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of 'class HtmlBuilder'
7 | class HtmlBuilder;
```

I also tried to have a pointer to HtmlElement class in builder object. But, there was still the same error.

Comment: Missing `#include "HtmlElement.h"` in HtmlBuilder.h, and both `#include "HtmlElement.h #include "HtmlBuilder.h"` in HtmlElement.cpp

Comment: Should it be `static HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::create()`?

Comment: If there is a dependency cycle, you have to use pointers.

Comment: Thanks, @Jarod42 I missed to include "HtmlBuilder.h" in HtmlElement.cpp. This was causing the issue.

Comment: @drum It's already in class, so no. If you meant moving it to `HTMLBuilder`, then I'd join you. It doesn't look to me if elements should be able to create builders (even though the function is static).

Comment: @KamilCuk You don't _have_ to use pointers, at least not in this situation.

Comment: @juanchopanza Right about pointers, still, there's a cyclic include and we have `HtmlElement HtmlBuilder::build()` *and* `HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::create()` - and we need to resolve at *some* point.

Comment: @Aconcagua what do you mean moving method to `HtmlBuilder`? Is it like to access the following way - 
`HtlmElemnt e = HtmlBuilder::Build(). . .`

Comment: @panky Make it a function of class HtmlBuilder (`HtmlBuilder HtmlBuilder::create()`) - Probably even drop entirely - what would do the function a constructor could not?

Comment: A nice example of builder pattern (with explanations) is given here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/cpp/1 Maybe you can fix your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got into trouble:

```
class HtmlElement
{
public:
    static HtmlBuilder create(); // requires complete definition of HtmlBuilder
                                 // -> include HtmlBuilder.h
};

class HtmlBuilder
{
public:
    HtmlElement build();         // requires complete definition of HtmlElement
                                 // -> include HtmlBuilder.h
};
```

i. e. HtmlElement needs to include HtmlBuilder and vice versa, which is a cyclic include (unavoidable due to cyclic type dependency).

You need to break this dependency by whatever suitable means. One way could be letting `create` function return a pointer:

```
HtmlBuilder* HtmlElement::create();
// possibly better a smart pointer:
std::unique_ptr<HtmlBuilder> HtmlElement::create();
```

Question, though, is: Why do you need a static creator function at all? What could that function do more than a constructor? If you need to be able to distinguish different construction types, you might do so via tag types (similar to the [execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) used e. g. in [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)).

Comment: *"`HtmlBuilder create(); // requires complete definition of HtmlBuilder`"*. Wrong, forward declaration is enough, even if it might look strange.